# What are the exact steps to install a 2-disk RAID 1 Desktop Ubuntu 20.04 system?

Tags: system-installation, raid

I am trying to install a *Desktop* Ubuntu 20.04 with **RAID** 1 on a PC that has two hard disks of the same size.

I cannot find the dialog in the installer that matches the documentation I read on the subject.

The Ubuntu page https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation-advanced says "Follow the installation steps until you get to the *Guided storage configuration* step".

After the "Keyboard layout" step, I get to the "Updates and other software" step, where I choose "Normal installation". Then I get to "Installation type", where I choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu". (instead of "Something else"). On the next page I'm asked to select the drive: I can only choose between sda and sdb.

There is no mention of RAID or of a "Guided storage configuration".

Did I take the wrong turn, or am I using the wrong Live DVD?

I downloaded ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso on Sept. 4th, 2020.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do not want LVM, skip that part and just use standard ext4 partition(s). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066028/install-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios
https://askubuntu.com/questions/355727/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-with-uefi-and-raid1-lvm

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Ubuntu Server installer instead (ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso).

I followed the instructions by fevangelou at [Install Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa with RAID 1 on two devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices) to create a software RAID.

The server installer worked in text mode, and the system it installed booted in text mode also. I had to do the following to install a graphical desktop:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

After rebooting, I got a graphical login and the system appeared to work fine.

To reboot however, I had to power down the PC, because the shutdown had blocked with these lines on the screen:

```
[FAILED] Failed unmounting /tmp
[FAILED] Failed unmounting /cdrom
```

Perhaps the Server installer could offer the user to install ubuntu-desktop itself.

I thought the Desktop installer supported creating a software RAID. Perhaps I misremembered, as the last time I had to do that was several years ago.

Comment: Unfortunately if you don't have your video drivers right, it fails to load, and then you're stuck with Server. :-/